# url suffixes... what are they called, and how to use (like Youtube has ?&w=398&h=296)

Tags: url

In looking at the code for several embedded players, I see that a number of them use coding similar to YouTube where there is a suffix appended to the url like:

?&w=398&h=296

I see through experimentation that the same document is being fetched regardless of the suffix which tells me that it must be there to pass that data into the document, but is ignored for fetching the page.

First off, what is the terminology here?  I'd gladly look this stuff up and research it myself if I knew what to call it.  Secondly, how is this data being passed on?  Does it need to be referencing a particular api?  Something more basic?  Just looking for general concepts I can look into.

I'm not just talking about youtube.  I see other companies doing this with embeds that fetch a url from their servers.

edited to add:  So someone just stopped by and gave me a hit and run down vote without commenting... because I asked what something is called so I can spend time to look it up myself.  Brilliant.  You must be proud of your contribution to humanity.  Don't let me keep you.  A puppy needs kicking somewhere.

Comment: ["Query string"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entirety of the URL suffix is called a "query string". [See this image for some more parts of a URL](http://d2v4zi8pl64nxt.cloudfront.net/solving-the-subdomain-equation/5215862a840e17.67339757.jpg). It can be used in PHP, Node.js, and other server-side environments to determine which content to serve or to make small modifications to the content that will be served. I'm not familiar with PHP, but in Node, this is how you would use the values in a query string:

```js
let url = require('url'),
  {parse} = require('queryString'),
  {createServer} = require('http');
let server = createServer((req, res) => {
  let url = url.parse(req.url),
    query = parse(url.query);
  res.end(`You requested the ${url.pathname} directory with this query: ${query}.`);
}).listen(8080);
console.log('listening on *:8080');
```

This code simply starts a server at localhost:8080 and outputs the directory name and query string.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Ahh.  Yeah, I just wasn't able to look it up without the terminology.  Got it, and digging into now.  Thx.